# How to setup VPS(Virtual hosting server) in Godaddy

Tags: server, godaddy, virtualhost, vps, web-hosting

I recently purchase a VPS from GoDaddy. Now i need to Setup the virtual server to go ahead and install my website.

Please guide how to go about.

Thanks in advance

Comment: when you say install your website - be a bit more detailed please. Do you mean what will you need to get your website running on the VPS?

Comment: Initially i need to Setup up the Virtual hosting Server... then i need to host my website.

Comment: I would recommend asking how to set up a distro as a server for whatever OS you install on your VPS. -Edit- you might want to try http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to run some flavour of Linux in your VPS, the [GoDaddy documentation for Linux on VPS](http://community.godaddy.com/help/category/60/virtual-dedicated-linux/) should help to get you going.